# Can I disable HTML Sanitation on Spotfire X desktop?

Tags: html, spotfire, tibco, html-sanitizing

In Spotfire previous versions (7.0.2 and 7.11 for example) it was easy to turn HTML Sanitation on and off.

All I had to do was go to Tools -> Administration Manager -> Everyone -> Preferences -> Text Area -> TextAreaPreferences -> And set the PerformHtmlSanitation to False.

I can't find it anywhere on my Spotfire X (10.2.0) desktop. Actually, I can't even find the Administration Manager.

Does anyone know where this can be set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your post, this is because you're using the Desktop edition, not the Analyst edition. Desktop is a standalone, local-only version of the Analyst client; it cannot connect to a server, therefore there is nothing to administer. you should see this right away if you get the Analyst client.